# Build size 10.6 MB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, build, create-react-app

I am using Create-react-app for my application. When I run npm run build, my build size is 10.6 MB. When I used source-map-explorer to analyze i got know my node modules are taking 6.3 MB and my components takes 2.84 MB, 780 KB for static and other for containers and reducers.

Kindly help me to reduce my build size.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you `eject` the project and made custom webpack configuration for it? if so, please add it to the question.

Comment: @SultanH. I did not eject.

Comment: Can you show a good screenshot for the _source-map-explorer_ output?

Comment: I have added image in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's painful!

You have multiple packages `antd`, `material-ui`, `cpexcel`, `froala-editor` ...etc
These packages are awesome, but the problem is they are very large ones.

You can have these notes to be considered for reducing the bundle size:

1. [Code-Splitting and Lazy loading.](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html).
2. Don't import any static failes inside your app, it will be dealt with as a dependency and be included at your bundle, instead, use CDNs for your static files.
3. Remove any un-used packages out of your `package.json` CLEAN IT UP.
4. Remove any un-used `import` statements in your application.

These can bring major changes to your bundle size, depending on how much you put effort on them.

The other way might be ejecting the app, and customly set Webpack Configurations yourself to deal with the specifications of your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving detailed answer. I trying to remove un-used packages but most of them are in use. And I am worried if eject then other things of app can get disturb.

Comment: I would not eject it, because it would do little to solve your r problem. You might want to consider to sticky with just one design lib and change your code to use only one.

Comment: I have updated CRA to latest version and removed unused packages and import. Finally my build size got divide in 5 and 3 MB and post CDN compression it reduced to 1.4 MB and 560 KB. Thank you Sultan and Domino987 for quick response.

Comment: I am so Glad you got it Anshul! Great job.